# Change content when clicks the button with reactjs & Material UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

The website is being developed using Reactjs and Material UI.

Switch statements were used to output different components each time the address was changed. And buttons are supposed to be moved to the URL using 'Link to'.

But I don't understand that when I press a button, it doesn't change to that component, but when I press the 'Drawer' button, it changes to that component.

I wonder what the problem is.
I think the problem is from three parts above. But full working codes are also here with CodeSandbox
[CodeSandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/example-create-react-app-express-4zs90?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fclient%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark)

**[Part of switch statement]**

```
let contentPlace;
let changePage = () =>{
  let location = window.location.pathname;
  console.log(location);
  switch(location){
    case '/':{
      contentPlace=<Home />
      break;
    }
    case '/login':{
      contentPlace=<SignIn/>
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**[Part of Buttons]**

```
<Button variant="outlined" color="inherit" onClick={changePage()}>
  Login
</Button>
</Link>
<Link to="/" className="home">
<Button variant="outlined" color="inherit"  onClick={changePage()}>
  HomE
</Button>
```

**[Part of Switch with React-dom-Router]**

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login">
    {/* <SignIn /> */}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/about">
    {/* <About /> */}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/users">
    {/* <Users /> */}
  </Route>
  <Route path="/">
  </Route>
    {/* <Home /> */}
</Switch>
```

It's working like this.
[image]

Comment: I think you should use `<Link>` component in `react-router-dom`, also your `onClick={changePage()}` should change to `onClick={changePage}` instead

Comment: FYI your sandbox is not working correctly.

Comment: And why is this question flagged in node js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not too sure why would you need a switch case for that. But you can take a look at this simple example. You don't need to wrap your `Button` with a `Link`, instead you can utilize [`component`](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#component-prop) props in `Button` to prevent unnecessary wrapping for your components.

```
const SignIn = () => (
  <div>
    This is sign in page.
    <Button component={Link} to="/home">
      To Home Page
    </Button>
  </div>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    This is home page.
    <Button component={Link} to="/login">
      To Login Page
    </Button>
  </div>
)

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
          <SignIn />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Comment: Because I have to put it in main part. In main part there is contentPlace variable. I thought this is working but it's not working. ```<Switch>
  <Route path="/login">{(contentPlace = <SignIn />)}</Route>
  <Route path="/about">{/* <About /> */}</Route>
  <Route path="/users">{/* <Users /> */}</Route>
  <Route path="/">{(contentPlace = <Home />)}</Route>
</Switch> ```

Comment: Do you mean both `login` and `home` will be in the path of `/`?